# How can I connect pyNetLogo to netlogo version 5

Tags: python, connection, version, netlogo

I want to use pyNetLogo to make a connection with NetLogo version 5.3.1. This should be done manually because by default it connects with NetLogo version 6. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can indicate the version of netlogo you are using when instantiating the NetLogoLink: https://pynetlogo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_docs/pynetlogo.html. However, in general you should not need to do this. On what OS are you? On Windows and MacOS pyNetLogo tries to guess the netlogo version by parsing the path of NetLogo Home.